# How to get the minimum of three different rules

Tags: prometheus, promql

I have three different recording rules that return either 0, 1 or 2. In another recording rule I want to get the minimum of those 3 metrics combined.

I have tried several different approaches, one that resembles a normal programming language like:

```
min by (label) (
 metric1{label!=""} 
 or 
 metric2{label!=""} 
 or 
 metric3{label!=""}
)
```

All three metrics here have the same labels.

This returns everything based on only the first metric, but I want to get the minimum value found between all of these metrics.

Answer (score 1):

After exploring a bit more, I've found a solution that seems to work:

```
min({__name__=~"metric1|metric2|metric3"})
```

This works, because all of the metrics have the same labels. Which might have been the reason why it was failing in the first place.

Will update if I find that it fails any edge case.

Comment: Ah, yes `or` will no do what you want it too, if metrics have exactly the same labels. I was a bit misled by `by (label)` part of your attempt(